# Why don't I need to use the import keyword when importing a library?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, import

I imported an external JAR to my project in Eclipse, by following these instructions:

Right click on the project > Build Path > Add external archives > Choosing the JAR file from the hard drive.

The JAR file than appears in the 'References libraries' section in my project, and works fine.

However, I never need to use the `import` keyword in my classes in order to use the classes from the JAR. I find this weird, I thought I'd have to use `import myImportedJar` or something similar for this to work.

Is it normal that I don't have to use the `import` keyword? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: What package are the relevant classes in?

Comment: You have a tens of jars in your project, It doesn't mean all the classes are imported in a single class. You have to import.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis All classes are in the default package. The imported JAR is in the References Libraries section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import` statement is used to be able to refer to types and their members by their simple names. You don't need to import classes that are in the same package, unless they are nested members of other classes. This is true regardless of where the class comes from, for example, if it's in another `.jar`.

Comment: Does that mean that it doesn't matter what JAR a class is in - it only matters what **package** it's in? Meaning, if class A is inside a JAR imported to the project from the outside, and class B was created inside the project - and both have no explicitly defined packages - it means that both of them are in the same package, the default one?

Comment: @Prog That's right. A `jar` is simply a solution for grouping `.class` files. In the end, when you provide a classpath to the JVM, it's all a bunch of `.class` files in corresponding packages.  There's no differentiation between `.class` files in `jars` or anywhere else.

Comment: So I don't need to write `import` because the class from the imported JAR is also in the default package?

Comment: @Prog Right. The same thing would happen if your class was in package `org.example` and some other class was also in that package but it was in a separate jar on the classpath. This behavior doesn't only apply to the default package.

Answer (score 1):

The import keyword works on a package level. If these packages are supplied by jars or not is not a feature of the java programming language.

import only makes a name available in unqualified form in your program. The following code fragments are identical:

```
java.util.List<Object> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>()
```

vs

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>()
```

Now, importing a jar file in eclipse puts the classes from this jarfile on the classpath - the total "world" of available classes for your application.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Got a question `java.util.List` - I'm not sure what this statement means. `List` is obviously a class. But what is `java` exactly and what is `util`? Libraries? JARs? Packages? Where do they come from? I don't completely understand.

Comment: The jre supplies a (rather comprehensive) standard library. This library contains classes you will most likely need to do anything serious with java. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ - these classes (organized in packages) are available to you _without_ any further jars, just because you installed java,